# FetchMode.SUBSELECT not using @OrderBy in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

> Does anyone know how to get `@OrderBy` annotations working with `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` in Spring Boot 3?

I have a Spring Boot application that uses `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `3.0.2`. It contains an entity that has a `@OneToMany` relationship that uses both `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` and an `@OrderBy`. The `@OrderBy` is not being used. Instead of child entities being in the order specified by the `@OrderBy` they appear in the order they were inserted into the database.

The failure to use the `@OrderBy` seems to be due to a combination of using Spring Boot 3 and `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`. I think this because:

- If I change the `FetchMode` to either `SELECT` or `JOIN` then the `@OrderBy` is used (even when using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `3.0.2`).
- If I revert back to `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.7.8` then the `@OrderBy` is used (even when using `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`).

Has anyone else noticed this problem when moving from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3? Is anyone aware of any workaround to get `@OrderBy` being used when using `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` with Spring Boot 3?

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@OrderBy("name ASC")
private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Example application with actual and expected results**

When running the `Application` class listed below I get the following output (children appear in the order they were inserted):

```
>> 1 b
>> 2 a
>> 3 c
```

I expected to get the following output (children appear ordered by name):

```
>> 2 a
>> 1 b
>> 3 c
```

I *do* get the expected output if in `Parent.java` I replace `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` with either `FetchMode.JOIN` or `FetchMode.SELECT`.

I *do* get the expected output if I alter the `pom.xml` to use `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.7.8`. (If I revert to `2.7.8` then I also need to alter `Parent.java` and `Child.java` to import from `javax.` rather than `jakarta.`)

**Application.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
   }

   @Bean
   public CommandLineRunner demo(ParentRepository parentRepository, ChildRepository childRepository) {
      return (args) -> {
         Parent parent = parentRepository.save(new Parent());
         childRepository.save(new Child(parent, "b"));
         childRepository.save(new Child(parent, "a"));
         childRepository.save(new Child(parent, "c"));

         for (Child child : parentRepository.findAll().get(0).getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(">> " + child.getId() + " " + child.getName());
         }
      };
   }
}
```

**ParentRepository.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Long> {
   @Override
   List<Parent> findAll();
}
```

**ChildRepository.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ChildRepository extends CrudRepository<Child, Long> {
}
```

**Parent.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OrderBy;

@Entity
public class Parent {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   @OrderBy("name ASC")
   private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

   public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public List<Child> getChildren() {
      return children;
   }

   public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
      this.children = children;
   }
}
```

**Child.java**

```
package com.example;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Child {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
   private Parent parent;

   @Column(name = "name", nullable = true)
   private String name;

   public Child(Parent parent, String name) {
      this.parent = parent;
      this.name = name;
   }

   public Child() {
   }

   public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public Parent getParent() {
      return parent;
   }

   public void setParent(Parent parent) {
      this.parent = parent;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>subselect-orderby-example</name>
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I have created the issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16202

Comment: Apologies. Based on the earlier comment I also created an issue for this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16203 before I read the comment about HHH-16202. You're welcome to close it if it doesn't provide anymore information than in HHH-16202. Thanks.